# Remote debugging via SSH Tunnel

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I would like to be able to debug an application through VSCode via SSH. So far I have create the debug configuration in VSCode and I have created a SSH tunnel on the correct port.

So far, this works fine. I can connect to the remote application using `node inspect <host>:<port>` and I can attach via VSCode. I have veryfied both using the `Dabugger attached.` log line in the remote application.

However, things start to break when I actually use the VSCode debugger. I.e. if a breakpoint should be triggered, I get an error instead. This is because the application tries to require a module that is anly available on my local machine and not the remote one:

[image]

My guess is that this is because VSCode does not even know that it is being tunnled to a different machine and still assumes that it is on my local machine. Are there any ways to solve this?

By the way, this is my launch configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "Debug Docker",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "address": "localhost",
    "restart": true,
    "port": 9228,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
    "remoteRoot": "/app/dist",
    "presentation": {
        "order": 1
    },
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js"]
}
```

And this is the SSH Tunnel command:

```bash
ssh -nNT -L 9228:localhost:9229 remote-system.example.org
```